# Mostrar Imagen en Nav Header con Kotlin

Tags: android, firebase, kotlin, android-fragment

Necesito mostrar la imagen de perfil de usuario en el nav header. Ya he logrado subir la imagen a Firebase Storage, guardar la referencia de al imagen en Firebase Database, cree un Fragment llamado SettingFragment donde se cargan los datos que luego quedan guardados en la base de datos. Pero al momento de setear la imagen en el Nav Header no la muestra y solo aparece la imagen por defecto.

Este es el HomeActivity

```
import android.os.Bundle
import android.view.LayoutInflater
import android.view.Menu
import android.view.ViewGroup
import android.widget.ImageView
import android.widget.TextView
import com.google.android.material.floatingactionbutton.FloatingActionButton
import com.google.android.material.snackbar.Snackbar
import com.google.android.material.navigation.NavigationView
import androidx.navigation.findNavController
import androidx.navigation.ui.AppBarConfiguration
import androidx.navigation.ui.navigateUp
import androidx.navigation.ui.setupActionBarWithNavController
import androidx.navigation.ui.setupWithNavController
import androidx.drawerlayout.widget.DrawerLayout
import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity
import androidx.appcompat.widget.Toolbar
import androidx.recyclerview.widget.LinearLayoutManager
import androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView
import com.alexanderdev.ecommerce.Model.Products
import com.alexanderdev.ecommerce.Prevalent.Prevalent
import com.alexanderdev.ecommerce.Prevalent.Prevalent.currentOnlineUser
import com.alexanderdev.ecommerce.Model.Users
import com.alexanderdev.ecommerce.ViewHolder.ProductViewHolder
import com.firebase.ui.database.FirebaseRecyclerAdapter
import com.firebase.ui.database.FirebaseRecyclerOptions
import com.google.firebase.analytics.connector.AnalyticsConnectorImpl.getInstance
import com.google.firebase.database.DatabaseReference
import com.google.firebase.database.FirebaseDatabase
import com.google.firebase.ktx.Firebase
import com.squareup.picasso.Picasso
import de.hdodenhof.circleimageview.CircleImageView
import kotlinx.android.synthetic.main.content_main.*
import kotlinx.android.synthetic.main.nav_header_main.*
import java.security.Policy.getInstance
import java.util.Calendar.getInstance
import java.util.Currency.getInstance

class HomeActivity : AppCompatActivity() {


    private lateinit var appBarConfiguration: AppBarConfiguration


    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_home2)
        val toolbar: Toolbar = findViewById(R.id.toolbar)
        setSupportActionBar(toolbar)
        val drawerLayout: DrawerLayout = findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout)
        val navView: NavigationView = findViewById(R.id.nav_view)
        val headerView = navView.getHeaderView(0)
        val userNameTextView = headerView.findViewById(R.id.user_profile_name) as TextView
        val profileImageView = headerView.findViewById<CircleImageView>(R.id.user_profile_image)
        userNameTextView.text = currentOnlineUser.nombre
        Picasso.get().load(currentOnlineUser.imagen).placeholder(R.drawable.profile).into(profileImageView)



        val navController = findNavController(R.id.nav_host_fragment)




        val fab: FloatingActionButton = findViewById(R.id.fab)
        fab.setOnClickListener { view ->
            Snackbar.make(view, "Replace with your own action", Snackbar.LENGTH_LONG)
                    .setAction("Action", null).show()
        }
```

> El Setting Fragment

```
@file:Suppress("UNREACHABLE_CODE")

package com.alexanderdev.ecommerce.ui.setting

import android.app.Activity
import android.app.Activity.RESULT_OK
import android.app.ProgressDialog
import android.content.Context
import android.content.Intent
import android.net.Uri
import androidx.lifecycle.ViewModelProviders
import android.os.Bundle
import android.os.Handler
import android.provider.ContactsContract.ProfileSyncState.set
import android.provider.MediaStore
import android.provider.Settings.Global.getString
import android.text.TextUtils
import android.util.Log
import androidx.fragment.app.Fragment
import android.view.LayoutInflater
import android.view.View
import android.view.ViewGroup
import android.widget.EditText
import android.widget.TextView
import android.widget.Toast
import androidx.core.app.ActivityCompat.*
import com.alexanderdev.ecommerce.MainActivity
import com.alexanderdev.ecommerce.Model.Users
import com.alexanderdev.ecommerce.Prevalent.Prevalent
import com.alexanderdev.ecommerce.R
import com.google.android.gms.common.internal.Objects
import com.google.android.gms.tasks.Continuation
import com.google.android.gms.tasks.Task
import com.google.firebase.database.*
import com.google.firebase.database.core.Tag
import com.google.firebase.storage.FirebaseStorage
import com.google.firebase.storage.StorageReference
import com.google.firebase.storage.StorageTask
import com.google.firebase.storage.UploadTask
import com.squareup.picasso.Picasso
import com.theartofdev.edmodo.cropper.CropImage
import com.theartofdev.edmodo.cropper.CropImageView
import de.hdodenhof.circleimageview.CircleImageView
import kotlinx.android.synthetic.main.fragment_settings.*
import kotlinx.android.synthetic.main.fragment_settings.view.*
import kotlinx.android.synthetic.main.nav_header_main.view.*
import java.lang.reflect.Array.set
import com.alexanderdev.ecommerce.HomeActivity as HomeActivity1

@Suppress("DEPRECATION")
class SettingsFragment : Fragment() {
   var usersReference: DatabaseReference? = null
   private val RequestCode = 1234
   private var imageUri: Uri ?= null
   private var storageProfilePictureRef: StorageReference? = null
   private var checker: String = ""


   override fun onCreateView(
       inflater: LayoutInflater, container: ViewGroup?,
       savedInstanceState: Bundle?
   ): View? {


      val view =  inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_settings, container, false)

       usersReference = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().reference.child("Users").
       child(Prevalent.currentOnlineUser.telefono)
       storageProfilePictureRef = FirebaseStorage.getInstance().reference.child("Imagenes de Perfil")

       usersReference!!.addValueEventListener(object : ValueEventListener{
           override fun onDataChange(snapshot: DataSnapshot) {
                   if (snapshot.child("imagen").exists())
                   {
                       val imagen = snapshot.child("imagen").getValue().toString()
                       val nombre = snapshot.child("nombre").getValue().toString()
                       val apellido = snapshot.child("apellido").getValue().toString()
                       val telefono = snapshot.child("telefono").getValue().toString()
                       val direccion = snapshot.child("direccion").getValue().toString()

                       Picasso.get().load(imagen).into(view.user_profile_image)
                       view.settings_name.setText(nombre)
                       view.settings_lastname.setText(apellido)
                       view.settings_phone_number.setText(telefono)
                       view.settings_direction.setText(direccion)


                   }
           }

           override fun onCancelled(error: DatabaseError) {

           }
       })

       view.close_settings_btn.setOnClickListener {

           activity?.onBackPressed()

       }

       view.update_account_settings_btn.setOnClickListener {

           userInfoSaved()
       }

       view.settings_profile_image.setOnClickListener{
           checker = "clicked"


           context?.let { it1 ->
               CropImage.activity()
                   .setAspectRatio(1,1)
                   .start(it1, this)



           }






       }

       return view


   }
   override fun onActivityResult(requestCode: Int, resultCode: Int, data: Intent?) {
       super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data)
       if (requestCode == CropImage.CROP_IMAGE_ACTIVITY_REQUEST_CODE && resultCode == RESULT_OK && data!=null) {

           val result = CropImage.getActivityResult(data)

           imageUri = result.uri

           settings_profile_image.setImageURI(imageUri)

           Toast.makeText(context, "Estamos guardado la imagen", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show()


           userInfoSaved()




       }
   }

   private fun updateOnlyUserInfo()
   {
       val ref = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().reference.child("Users")

       val userMap = HashMap<String, Any>()
       userMap.put("Nombre", settings_name.text.toString())
       userMap.put("Apellido", settings_lastname.text.toString())
       userMap.put("Telefono", settings_phone_number.text.toString())
       userMap.put("Direccion", settings_direction.text.toString())


       ref!!.child(Prevalent.currentOnlineUser.telefono).updateChildren(userMap)




       val intent = Intent(context, HomeActivity1::class.java)
       startActivity(intent)

       Toast.makeText(context, "Informacion de perfil Actualizada", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show()

       activity?.onBackPressed()

   }

   private fun userInfoSaved() {
      if (TextUtils.isEmpty(settings_name.text.toString()))
      {
          Toast.makeText(context, "Por favor escriba su nombre", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show()
      }
       else if (TextUtils.isEmpty(settings_lastname.text.toString()))
      {
          Toast.makeText(context, "Por favor escriba su apellido", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show()
      }
       else if (TextUtils.isEmpty(settings_phone_number.text.toString()))
      {
          Toast.makeText(context, "Por favor escriba su numero de telefono", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show()
      }
       else if (TextUtils.isEmpty(settings_direction.text.toString()))
      {
          Toast.makeText(context, "Por favor escriba su direccion", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show()
      }
       else
      {
          uploadImageToDatabase()
      }
   }





   private fun uploadImageToDatabase() {

       val progressBar= ProgressDialog(context)
       progressBar.setMessage("La imagen esta siendo guardada, por favor espere un momento")
       progressBar.show()

       if(imageUri!=null){

           val fileRef = storageProfilePictureRef!!.
           child(Prevalent.currentOnlineUser.telefono + ".jpg")

           var uploadTask: StorageTask<*>
           uploadTask= fileRef.putFile(imageUri!!)
           uploadTask.continueWithTask(Continuation <UploadTask.TaskSnapshot, Task<Uri>> { task ->

               if(!task.isSuccessful){
                   task.exception?.let {
                       throw it
                   }

               }
               return@Continuation fileRef.downloadUrl
           }).addOnCompleteListener { task ->

               if(task.isSuccessful)
               {
                   val downloadUrl = task.result
                   val myUrl = downloadUrl.toString()
                   val ref = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().reference.child("Users")

                   val userMap = HashMap<String, Any>()
                   userMap.put("Nombre", settings_name.text.toString())
                   userMap.put("Apellido", settings_lastname.text.toString())
                   userMap.put("Telefono", settings_phone_number.text.toString())
                   userMap.put("Direccion", settings_direction.text.toString())
                   userMap.put("Imagen", myUrl)

                   ref!!.child(Prevalent.currentOnlineUser.telefono).updateChildren(userMap)

                   progressBar.dismiss()


                   val intent = Intent(context, HomeActivity1::class.java)
                   startActivity(intent)

                   Toast.makeText(context, "Informacion de perfil Actualizada", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show()


               }

               else
               {
                   progressBar.dismiss()
                   Toast.makeText(context, "Se produjo un error", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show()
               }
           }
       }
       else 
       {
           Toast.makeText(context, "No se ha seleccionado una imagen valida", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show()
       }
   }
}
```

La Clase Users

```
package com.alexanderdev.ecommerce.Model;
public class Users {
    private String nombre, telefono, clave, imagen, direccion;

    public Users()
    {

    }

    public Users(String nombre, String telefono, String clave, String imagen, String direccion) {
        this.nombre = nombre;
        this.telefono = telefono;
        this.clave = clave;
        this.imagen = imagen;
        this.direccion = direccion;
    }

    public String getNombre() {
        return nombre;
    }

    public void setNombre(String nombre) {
        this.nombre = nombre;
    }

    public String getTelefono() {
        return telefono;
    }

    public void setTelefono(String telefono) {
        this.telefono = telefono;
    }

    public String getClave() {
        return clave;
    }

    public void setClave(String clave) {
        this.clave = clave;
    }

    public String getImagen() {
        return imagen;
    }

    public void setImagen(String imagen) {
        this.imagen = imagen;
    }

    public String getDireccion() {
        return direccion;
    }

    public void setDireccion(String direccion) {
        this.direccion = direccion;
    }
}
```

Los datos quedan guardados en la base de datos pero no se muestra la imagen en el ImageView

Aqui esta el Xml de Nav Header

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="@dimen/nav_header_height"
    android:background="@color/colorPrimaryDark"
    android:gravity="bottom"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    android:theme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Dark">

    <de.hdodenhof.circleimageview.CircleImageView
        android:id="@+id/user_profile_image"
        android:layout_width="96dp"
        android:layout_height="96dp"
        android:src="@drawable/profile"
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        app:civ_border_width="2dp"
        app:civ_border_color="@android:color/white"/>

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/user_profile_name"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        android:paddingTop="8dp"
        android:textSize="20sp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="4dp"
        android:textStyle="bold"
        android:text="Nombre de Usuario" />
</LinearLayout>
```

Answer (score 0):

Una vez te logueas con el usuario , si la imagen es personalizada y no viene de algun proveedor como Google , Facebook, Twitter, etc, lo que deberias hacer es hacer un updateProfile para poder actualizar los campos por defecto que el currentUser tiene, de esta forma los puedes acceder luego cuando quieras sin necesidad de ir a la base de datos a buscar estos metadatos.

Documentacion: https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/android/manage-users?hl=es#update_a_users_profile

### Implementacion

```
val user = FirebaseAuth.getInstance().currentUser

val profileUpdates = UserProfileChangeRequest.Builder()
        .setDisplayName("Jane Q. User")
        .setPhotoUri(Uri.parse("https://example.com/jane-q-user/profile.jpg"))
        .build()

user?.updateProfile(profileUpdates)
        ?.addOnCompleteListener { task ->
            if (task.isSuccessful) {
                Log.d(TAG, "User profile updated.")
            }
        }
```

Entonces, al actualizar los datos de ese currentUser en el callback de exito de tu login, cuando accedas a tu app, puedes llamar desde cualquier lado

```
FirebaseAuth.getInstance().currentUser.getPhotoUrl()
```

Una sugerencia es que no accedas estaticamente al valor de currentUser como lo estás haciendo sino que trates de obtener una instancia en cada lugar donde lo necesites, ya `FirebaseAuth` maneja ese singleton con el `getInstance()` por ti, haciendo asi que cada llamada devuelva siempre la misma instancia, por ende es menos propenso a que tengas algun problema al acceder a esa instancia